# How to parse non Latin data using ANTLR4?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse a text file using antlr4 which contains non Latin character like Arabic or Persian.

I've tried to define a unicode range like
`ID: ('\u0600'..'\u06FF')+ ;` but I get "token recognition error".

What is the proper way to handle this case?

Comment: (self ad, I know, but) Maybe you want to have a look at [grappa](https://github.com/fge/grappa). It has Unicode support.